# Java: Run an .exe program and get exery pixel of the GUI output

Tags: java

How can I call an .exe file on java (a game for example) and get every pixel of the output everytime I need it (every frame as example) ?

Comment: depends on the program, you run. Strarting a program is simpel: `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` but getting the window is not as simpel. If the programm is running on gpu you just wont be able to do it, if it runs on CPU you could make screenshots of the window, have a look at java Robot klass

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464593/how-to-capture-selected-screen-of-other-application-using-java